# Split results into 5 columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a query like:

```
$results = Post::all();
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's say the output is this (by `id`):

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

My website has a 5-column layout. I need to split/divide these results into 5 columns such that it ends up like this:

```
 1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5
 6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10
11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15
```

The 5 column layout is split like this (the total number of columns is 25):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        //
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        //
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        //
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        //
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        //
    </div> 
</div>
```

How can I split `$results` up like this? Any way to make use of Laravel's [Collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#available-methods)?

Comment: I have no idea about Laravel's collection methods, but a method you can use is to use a loop with a counter and when counter modulus 5 = 0, start a new row.

Comment: make a for loop like this maybe? `if ((i/5) == .2) row = 1; if (i/5 == .4) row == 2;` Not the most elegant but should work.

Answer (score 4):

Try this , i think it should give you the expected result

```
$chunks = $results->chunk(5);
 dd($chunks->toarray());
```

**Laravel Docs**

> The chunk method breaks the collection into multiple, smaller
>   collections of a given size

also it can be used in the View like this ( keep the same query in the controller and do the splitting in the View)

**EDIT**

```
             @foreach ($results->chunk(5) as $chunk)
                 <div class="row">
                      @foreach ($chunk as $test)
                   <div class="col-md-2">
                     {{ $test->id }}
                   </div>
                      @endforeach
                 </div>
              @endforeach
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Close, but doing this outputs it into columns like this: http://pastebin.com/raw/kZ0rqu82

Comment: i dont understand ? what is the output of my the code in my answer? can you show me

Comment: I added the HTML layout in my question to make it clearer. The layout NEEDS to be like that.

Comment: I edited the answer , that should work i guess you only have to work around it thats all

Comment: Like I said, it still outputs the content like this: http://pastebin.com/raw/kZ0rqu82

Comment: dude please , can you show me the output of my code? because as far as i know, its the same as the static html that you show me( they will be a row for each 5 elements and a column for each element of these 5 , what is wrong)

Comment: Here is how it's outputted: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21fdf07915fcea7722ba2f4a92c8d99b544159e8

Comment: i meant the output in the generated html file using the foreach loop, i dont realy understand your needs tbh

Answer (score 0):

I think @AchrafKhouadja was right, you can use either `array_chunk()` or Collection `chunk()`, here is an example how to render it to be like what you've expected:

```
$cells = range(1, 25)
$rows  = array_chunk($cells, 5);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<div class="row">';

    foreach ($row as $cell) {
        echo '<div class="col-xs-5">' . $cell . '</div>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

And the output would be:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">5</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">7</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">9</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">10</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">11</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">12</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">13</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">14</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">15</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">16</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">17</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">18</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">19</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">20</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">21</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">22</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">23</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">24</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">25</div>
</div>
```