# How to chunk results into 3 columns

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5, chunks

I have a set of results (e.g. [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]).

Which I want to be displayed as 1 row with 3 columns

```
1|5|9
2|6|10
3|7|11
4|8|
```

What I get is 1 row with 4 columns

```
1|4|7
2|5|8
3|6|9

10|
11|
```

Until I add a 12th object then I get 1 row with 3 columns

```
1|5|9
2|6|10
3|7|11
4|8|12
```

My code in blade template

```html
<!-- partials/tables/table_list.blade.php -->

@section('tables')
<?php $chunkSize = floor(count($tables) / 3); ?>
<section id="tables-overview">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($tables->chunk($chunkSize , 1) as $chunk)
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @include('partials.tables.table_chunk')
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</section>
@endsection

<!-- partials/tables/table_chunk.blade.php -->

<table class="table table-responsive">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">@lang('table.identifier')</th>
        <th class="text-center">@lang('table.property')</th>
        <th class="text-center">
            @permission('manage-tables')
                <a href="{{ route('CreateTable') }}">@lang('action.create')</a>
            @endpermission
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach ($chunk as $table)
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $table->getId() }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $table->getProperty() }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            @permission('manage-tables')
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('UpdateTable', ['id' => $table->getId()]) }}">@lang('action.update')</a>
            @endpermission
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach

</tbody>
</table>
```

When the number of $tables can be divided by 3 (number of columns I want) I get 3 chunks. If not I get 3 chunks + the remaining 1 or 2 objects which both get put in a 4th column. I can place them horizontally as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066878/split-results-into-5-columns/38066912#38066912) but I find this to be 'odd'. When reading a list you read from top to bottom first and then left to right.

**UPDATE**
I also tried using ceil() as suggested by *Huzaib Shafi*. But then I get

```
4 objects (funny looking)
1|3|
2|4|

5 objects (better looking)
1|3|5
2|4
```

which is also not 100% what I wanted but is pretty close to it. I will try the suggestion of *Homam Alhaytham* next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `floor` the division result, you get the lower number.

**Explanation:** floor(11/3) = 3. Hence your result gets chunked 3 at a time (resulting in; [3,3,3,2]), however we need [4,4,3].

So you need to `ceil` it. Giving you 4, thus the result.

```
<?php $chunkSize = ceil(count($tables) / 3); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

after you get $items by fetch database data and use loop example

```
$c=0;
echo '<div class="row">';
while(bla bla bla ..){
// counter
$c++;
echo '<div class="col-md-4">
some thing 
        </div>';
if(fmod($c,3)==0){
echo '</div><div class="row">';
}
}

echo '</div>';
```

here i used fmod($c,3) 3 number off your columns and fmod return 0 if $c is 6,9,12,15,18.....

Comment: I have also considered doing it this way, just think using the chunk method is cleaner, shorter and easier. Regardless of that I might just do it like this.

Answer (score -1):

Use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

Assuming you have the following array:

```
[
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    11,
];
```

In your `.blade.php` file you can do something like this:

```
@section('tables')
<section id="tables-overview">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (array_chunk($tables, 3) as  $chunk)
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @foreach($chunk as $key => $value)
            //@include('partials.tables.table_chunk')
            // No need to include anything here
            // just write your table instead of including
            @endforeach
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</section>
@endsection
```

Comment: I split my views into smaller partials, it makes them more readable to me. And some of those tiny partials are included in more then one view.